# Как интерполировать произвольную строку произвольным JSON?

Tags: python, json

Я создал таблицу уведомлений в своей базе данных. Я не знаю заранее, как будет выглядеть сообщение уведомления, но я знаю, что оно может быть очень сложным и включать в себя не только текст, но и HTML вставки, списки, сложные вложенные объекты и т.д.
Чтобы сделать таблицу уведомлений, я добавил в таблицу текстовое поле `message` и JSON поле `associated_data`. Я планирую хранить в поле `message` сырую строку, которая будет интерполирована данными из JSON поля сложным образом.
Я бы хотел иметь что-то такое:

```
    # 1)
    message = "Пакет был изменён!"
    associated_data = {}
    

    # 2)
    message = "Пользователь предложил изменить пакет {0}"
    associated_data = {"package":42}
    

    # 2)
    message = "Пакет {0} требует наличия не менее {features.count} функций компании {company.name} в городе {company.location.city}"
    associated_data = {"package":42, "features":{"count":12, "items":[...]}, "company":{"name":"Contoso", "location":{"city":"Saint Petersburg"}}}
```

Сейчас я использую:

```
associated_data = instance.associated_data
message=instance.message
return message.format(*[value for _, value in json.loads(associated_data).items()])
```

И это работает максимум для первых двух случаев. Есть ли эффективный и эффектный способ интерполировать строку словарём? Мне на ум приходит только функция типа:

```
def custom_interpolate(raw_string, json_data)
```

И да, я действительно не знаю схему уведомлений. В них может быть что угодно и оно динамически изменяется от уведомления к уведомлению. Есть гарантия, что `message` всегда соответствует `associated_data`.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148535/discussion-on-question-by-aycon-----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Comment: Но один комментарий я верну на видное место - вот так format умеет работать с вложенными объектами: `"{features[count]}".format(features={"count": 12})`

Comment: Ещё можно использовать `str.format_map(mapping)`